# SQL statement joining 3 Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g, inner-join, outer-join

I have reviewed several sites and numerous tutorials trying to determine the closest match for my situation and while I find many similar possible resolutions, no exact solution gives me what I think I need. With each attempt I either returned incorrect data, duplicate or unable to return all fields desired. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks, Newbie

I have three tables, they each share a primary_key of SUBR_ID. In lay terms, I am trying to extract BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER from TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER for all SUBR_ID and sub INDV_ID (one-to-many) where GRP_ID = '0G0000000', selecting first name, last name, and subscriber ID, Individual ID, and benefit carry over. Below are the referenced three tables and the statement attempts tried.

```
TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER:
SUBR_ID
INDV_ID
BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER

TBL_SUBR_GRP:
SUBR_ID
GRP_ID

TBL_SUBR_INDV:
SUBR_ID
INDV_ID
LNME
FNME
```

Attempt#1

```
select DISTINCT DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.SUBR_ID, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.INDV_ID, LNME, FNME, GRP_ID, BENEFIT_YEAR, BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER  
from DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER, 
     DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP, 
     DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV
where DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.SUBR_ID = DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID = DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.SUBR_ID
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.GRP_ID = '0G0000000'
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER > '0'
```

Attempt#2

```
select DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.INDV_ID, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.LNME, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.FNME, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.GRP_ID, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.BENEFIT_YEAR, DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER  
from DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV
join DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP on ( 
     where DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.SUBR_ID = DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID = DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.SUBR_ID
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.GRP_ID = '0G0000000'
     and DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER > '0'
```

Attempt#3

```
 SELECT LNME, FNME, SUBR_ID, INDV_ID
 FROM DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV
 WHERE DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV.SUBR_ID IN
        (SELECT BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER
        FROM DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER
        WHERE DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER.SUBR_ID IN
            (SELECT SUBR_ID
            FROM DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP
            WHERE DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP.GRP_ID = '0G0000000')
    )
```

Comment: Is benefit_year on the carry-over table, and do you want to see it in the query results?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the duplicates occur because a single individual can have many carry-over records. Therefore, try:

```
select i.SUBR_ID, 
       i.INDV_ID, 
       max(i.LNME) LNME, 
       max(i.FNME) FNME, 
       max(g.GRP_ID) GRP_ID, 
       o.BENEFIT_YEAR, 
       sum(o.BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER) BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER
from DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_GRP g
join DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV i
  on g.SUBR_ID = i.SUBR_ID
join DCS2000.TBL_SUBR_INDV_CARRY_OVER o
  on i.SUBR_ID = o.SUBR_ID and i.INDV_ID = o.INDV_ID and o.BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER > 0
where g.GRP_ID = '0G0000000' 
group by i.SUBR_ID, 
         i.INDV_ID, 
         o.BENEFIT_YEAR
```

Note that the individual table needs to be joined to the carry-over table by both the subscriber *and* the individual ID; also, that numeric fields (such as `BENEFIT_CARRY_OVER`) should not have quotes around their values.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was able to validate the totals for each indivdual for comparison. Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that due to the one to many, a simple join across all three tables will give a duplicate row for the data you are interested in.  The join has to make an entire row for every row joined together.  Whereas what you want is a single row.

I often find that to build a complex query is best done in parts

So, first to find all the ids with the value of interest, with a single row for each.  It I'll shorten names somewhat due to the keyboard i am using.

Select distinct subr_id from subrgrp where grpid = 0000006

Then combine this with the next table up

Select distinct indvid from subrindv where subrid in (Select distinct subr_id from subrgrp where grpid = 0000006)

Then select the final rows of interest.

Select carryover from subrindv where indvid in (Select distinct indvid from subrindv where subrid in (Select distinct subr_id from subrgrp where grpid = 0000006))

The alternative is to use GROUP BY to group multiple rows into one.